# How to pass a variable in callbacks during rspec testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller, rspec-rails

I have callback name authenticatie_admin_user . It will return true if current user email ID is "adminuser@admin.com"

```
def authenticate_admin_user!
 if Current.user.blank? || Current.user.email != "adminuser@admin.com"
  redirect_to courses_path, danger: "Admin login required" 
 end 
end
```

This callback runs when I call new action .
While testing the new action I have to set Current.user value

```
describe "GET /new" do
    describe "Create course with admin login"
      it "will not renders a new course page" do
        get new_course_url
        expect(response).to_not be_successful
      end
      it "will render a new course page" do
        get new_course_url
        expect(response).to be_successful
      end
  end
```

How can I set the value of Current.user?
PS: Here Current is a ActiveSupport::Currentattributes model and user is a attribute inside Current class.

Comment: Can you mock it?

Comment: How to do that ? I dont understand

Comment: Sachin's answer as an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try stubbing the user object:

```rb
let(:user) { double(:user, email: 'adminuser@admin.com') }

before do
  allow(Current).to receive(:user).and_return(user)
end
```

or just

```rb
before do
  allow(Current).to receive(:user).and_return(nil)
end
```

Comment: nice, `instance_double(User)` is preferred (it will fail if you tried to stub it with a method that does not exist on the `User` object.